# Best Zero-Config Powerline or 802.11 Bridge

Tags: router, wifi, bridge

Need to ship a device to a remote non-technical user for connecting a device that only supports an ethernet cable, and no physical port in the same room.

Some of the Linksys devices (Powerline adapters) have been discontinued... any recommendations for the best zero-config device to bridge physical ethernet connections over 802.11 or power line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of WiFi access points you have deployed and what type of wireless security you're using on the network.

I would recommend an Apple AirPort Express or any D-Link/Linksys "game adapter". That should work with any 802.11 network that's using a pre-shared key. If you need something more enterprise-grade, you should look for something called a "workgroup bridge".

Answer (score 2):

.. Discontinued? There is a multi-vendor supported specification called [HomePlug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug_Powerline_Alliance) nowadays, maybe the adapters you were thinking about used some proprietary standard and were discontinued for that reason?

While I do lack personal experience in this field, I *have* heard people saying good things about HomePlug adapters [such as this one from Netgear](http://www.netgear.com/Products/PowerlineNetworking/PowerlineEthernetAdapters/HDX101.aspx), for example.